# How to optimize mysql group by with DATE_FORMAT

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization, sql-date-functions

I have a sql.

```
select  count(id) as total, DATE_FORMAT(create_time,"%Y-%m-%d") as create_date
    from  table_name
    group by  DATE_FORMAT(create_time,"%Y-%m-%d");
```

Then Definition of column create_time.

```
`create_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

As far as I know, the function **DATE_FORMAT** does not take the index, so my execution speed is very slow. Is there any way to optimize it?

> mysql version:5.6.34

Comment: I don't think there is a way to optimize this in MySQL.  I am curious if anyone knows a trick.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If we can't optimize, then how do we solve the slow query in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a generated column and create an index on that column:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN create_date DATE AS (DATE(create_time)) VIRTUAL;
CREATE INDEX idx ON table_name(create_date);
```

Since the generated column is virtual, it will not use any space.  (However, the index will of course use extra space.)  You can then use this generated column in your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), create_date FROM t2 GROUP BY create_date;
```

Comment: Does mysql5.6 support Virtual Generated Column?

Comment: No, you need MySQL 5.7

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I can't upgrade mysql

Comment: Does the query increase the value of the status variable "Created_tmp_disk_tables"?  If so, it may help to increase the size of both max_heap_table_size and tmp_table_size.

Comment: Will this increase query speed?

Comment: A temporary table will be used to store the counts for each group.  If a an in-memory table can be used for this, it should be faster than if an ordinary MyISAM table is used.

Comment: I don't know the concept of a temporary table, I need a little time to understand

Comment: I understand your answer, I think it is a way to improve performance, but I want other ways, such as sql itself

Answer (score 0):

I would try taking LEFT(create_time,10), that should utilize the index.

Answer (score 0):

This won't speed it up, but it is cleaner:

```
select  count(*) as total,
        DATE(create_time) as create_date
    from  table_name
    group by  DATE(create_time);
```

`COUNT(id)` checks `id` for being `NOT NULL`; that is probably unnecessary.

`INDEX(create_time)` will help *some*, but all it will do is turn a "table scan" into an "index scan".

If this is a Data Warehouse application (zillions of write-once rows, lots of "reports"), then we can discuss ways to make queries like this run orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Yes, there is a large amount of data to be counted.

Comment: @Frank.Dai - Would it work to get subtotals each night?  Then the 'report' query will be very fast.  More: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables