# MySQL: Optimize left join on formatted date

Tags: mysql, datetime, mariadb, query-optimization, virtual-column

I'm trying to optimize the speed of this query:

```
      SELECT t.t_date td, v.visit_date vd
      FROM temp_dates t
      LEFT JOIN visits v ON DATE_FORMAT(v.visit_date, '%Y-%m-%d') = t.t_date
      ORDER BY t.t_date
```

v.visit_date is of type DATETIME and t.t_date is a string of format '%Y-%m-%d'.
Simply creating an index on v.visitdate didn't improve the speed. Therefore I intended to try the solution @oysteing gave here:
[How to optimize mysql group by with DATE_FORMAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50939499/how-to-optimize-mysql-group-by-with-date-format)
I successfully created a virtual column by this SQL
    `ALTER TABLE visits ADD COLUMN datestr varchar(10) AS (DATE_FORMAT(visit_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) VIRTUAL;`
However when I try to create an index on this column by
`CREATE INDEX idx_visit_date on visits(datestr)` I get this error:

> #1901 - Function or expression 'date_format()' cannot be used in the GENERATED ALWAYS AS clause of `datestr`

What am I doing wrong? My DB is Maria DB 10.4.8

Best regards - Ulrich

Comment: You should rather fix the right side and promote `t_date` to a `datetime`...

Comment: Note that functions cannot use indexes :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`date_format()` cannot be used for persistent generated columns either. And in an index it cannot be just virtual, it has to be persisted.

I could not find an explicit statement in the manual, but I believe this is due to the fact that the output of `date_format()` can depend on the locale and isn't strictly deterministic therefore.

Instead of `date_format()` you can build the string using deterministic functions such as `concat()`, `year()`, `month()`, `day()` and `lpad()`.

```
...
datestr varchar(10) AS (concat(year(visit_date),
                               '-',
                               lpad(month(visit_date), 2, '0'),
                               '-',
                               lpad(day(visit_date), 2, '0')))
...
```

But as I already mentioned in a comment, you're fixing the wrong end. Dates/times should never be stored as strings. So you should rather promote `temp_dates.t_date` to a `date` and use `date()` to extract the `date` portion of `visit_date` in the generated, indexed column

```
...
visit_date_date date AS (date(visit_date))
...
```

And you might also want to try to also index `temp_dates.t_date`.

Comment: Many thanks, switching to DATETIME and using DATE improved speed a lot, by more than a factor of 10. However additional questions arose. I'm gonna update my question later.

Comment: @Sempervivum: Glad to hear that. But for additional questions consider asking a new one so that this one can stay focused.

Comment: OK, I'm gonna do so and mark your answer as solution here.

Comment: Note, the 3 args form of [date_format](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date_format/) is deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```sql
SELECT t.t_date td, v.visit_date vd
  FROM temp_dates t
  LEFT JOIN visits v ON DATE(v.visit_date) = DATE(t.t_date)
 ORDER BY t.t_date
```

If so, there's a workable solution to your problem:

1. Add a `DATE` column using the deterministic `DATE()` function on your `visit_date` object. Like this.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE visits ADD COLUMN dateval DATE AS (DATE(visit_date)) VIRTUAL; 
   CREATE INDEX idx_visit_date on visits(dateval);
   ```
2. Then create a virtual column in the other table (the one with the nicely formatted dates jammed into your VARCHAR() column.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE temp_dates ADD COLUMN dateval DATE AS (DATE(t_date)) VIRTUAL;
   CREATE INDEX idx_temp_dates_date on temp_dates (dateval);
   ```

This works because `DATE()` is deterministic, unlike `DATE_FORMAT()`.

Then your query should be.

```sql
SELECT t.t_date td, v.visit_date vd
  FROM temp_dates t
  LEFT JOIN visits v ON v.dateval = t.dateval
 ORDER BY t.t_date
```

This solution gives you indexes on (virtual) `DATE` columns. That's nice because index matching on such columns is efficient.

But, your best solution is to change the datatype of `temp_date.t_date` from `VARCHAR()` to `DATE`.

Answer (score 1):

`DATE_FORMAT(expr, format)` cannot be used in virtual columns as it depends on the locale of the connection (MariaDB issue [MDEV-11553](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11553)).

A 3 argument form was created to [date_format](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date_format/) that adds locale.

`DATE_FORMAT(visit_date, '%Y-%m-%d', 'en_US')` is possible to use in virtual column expressions in MariaDB-10.3+ stable versions.

Using `DATE` or altering your query not to use functions around column expressions is definitely recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are not "sargeable".

Consider:

```
ON  v.visit_date >= t.t_date
AND v.visit_date  < t.t_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```